# Do I need to backup my Amazon S3 stuff?

Tags: amazon-s3

My understanding is that Amazon S3 is on a cloud like system and doesn't need to be backed up because they have all of that in place.  Am I understanding this correctly or should I still back it up?  I'm considering moving all my images to Amazon S3 instead of hosted locally on my server.

Comment: Sure, if you don't care about your digital stuff ......

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Even though Amazon itself may have redundancies, you probably want an off site backup just in case they decide they don't like you.  There was a recent posting about a hosting company (not Amazon) locking someone out of their system and basically holding everything hostage.

http://www.reddit.com/r/AskReddit/comments/e4ebn/?sort=new

SaaS is a great idea, but then you get people that do stuff like this and it gets scary.

Comment: it's just good common sense to have (at least one!) off-site backup at hand at all times....